# Parsing XML with php and save it to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have been asked to parse a simple file which is stored as an XML file, the data is to be then save it to a mysql.

However I have absolutely no clue what to do and after looking online all the examples given seem either too complicated for my problem or not the right solution. The XML file looks like this

games_scores.xml

```
<gesmes:Letter>
<gesmes:subject>Reference Scores</gesmes:subject>
-
<gesmes:Sender>
<gesmes:name>Game Information Scores</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
-
<Cube>
-
<Cube time="2010-10-13">
<Cube scores="GameA1" value="1.5803"/>
<Cube scores="GameA2" value="21.35"/>
............etc
<Cube scores="GameA15" value="135"/>
</Cube>
</Cube>
</gesmes:Letter>
```

then i must saved it to mysql existing, that's looks

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scrore_table` (
  `scrore_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `scrore_title` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '',
  `scores` varchar(15) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '',
  `decimal_place` char(1) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `value` float(15,8) NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`currency_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; ;

INSERT INTO `scrore_table` (`scrore_id`, `scrore_title`, `scores`, `decimal_place`, `value`, `date_updated`) VALUES
(1, 'Game Class A0', 'GameA0', '2', 1.00000000, '2010-04-06 22:00:54'),
(2, 'Game Class A1', 'GameA1', '2', 1.58030000,  '2010-04-06 22:00:54'),
(3, 'Game Class A2', 'GameA2', '2', 21.3503000,  '2010-04-06 22:00:54'),
..............................etc
(15, 'Game Class A15', 'GameA15', '2', 135,  '2010-04-06 22:00:54');
```

directions to this issue i have php script by following:

```
<?php
class Scores_Converter {
   var $xml_file = "http://192.168.1.112/gamescores/games_scores.xml";
   var $mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $mysql_db, $mysql_table;
   var $scores_values = array();

   //Load convertion scores
   function Scores_Converter($host,$user,$pass,$db,$tb) {
      $this->mysql_host = $host;
      $this->mysql_user = $user;
      $this->mysql_pass = $pass;
      $this->mysql_db = $db;
      $this->mysql_table = $tb;

      $this->checkLastUpdated();

      $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host,$this->mysql_user,$this->mysql_pass); 
      $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db,$conn);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->mysql_table;
      $rs =  mysql_query($sql,$conn);   
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
         $this->scores_values[$row['scores']] = $row['value'];         
      }
   }

   /* Perform the actual conversion, defaults to 1.00 GameA1 to GameA3 */
   function convert($amount=1,$from="GameA1",$to="GameA3",$decimals=2) {     return(number_format(($amount/$this->scores_values[$from])*$this->scores_values[$to],$decimals));
   }

   /* Check to see how long since the data was last updated */
   function checkLastUpdated() {
      $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host,$this->mysql_user,$this->mysql_pass);

      $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db,$conn);
      $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM ".$this->mysql_db." LIKE '".$this->mysql_table."'";
      $rs =  mysql_query($sql,$conn);

      if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0 ) {
         $this->createTable();
      } else {
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
         if(time() > (strtotime($row["Update_time"])+(12*60*60)) ) {
            $this->downloadValueScores();         
         }
      }
   }

   /* Download xml file, extract exchange values and save the values in database */
   function downloadValueScores() {
      $scores_domain = substr($this->xml_file,0,strpos($this->xml_file,"/"));
      $scores_file = substr($this->xml_file,strpos($this->xml_file,"/"));
      $fp = @fsockopen($scores_domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
      if($fp) {
         $out = "GET ".$scores_file." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
         $out .= "Host: ".$scores_domain."\r\n";
         $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8) Gecko/20051111 Firefox/1.5\r\n";
         $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
         fwrite($fp, $out);
         while (!feof($fp)) {
            $buffer .= fgets($fp, 128);
         }
         fclose($fp);

         $pattern = "{<Cube\s*scores='(\w*)'\s*value='([\d\.]*)'/>}is";
         preg_match_all($pattern,$buffer,$xml_values);
         array_shift($xml_values);

         for($i=0;$i<count($xml_values[0]);$i++) {
            $exchange_value[$xml_values[0][$i]] = $xml_values[1][$i];
         }

         $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host,$this->mysql_user,$this->mysql_pass);
         $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db,$conn);

         foreach($exchange_value as $scores=>$value) {
            if((is_numeric($value)) && ($value != 0)) {
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$this->mysql_table." WHERE scores='".$scores."'";
               $rs =  mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
               if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
                  $sql = "UPDATE ".$this->mysql_table." SET value=".$value." WHERE scores='".$scores."'";
               } else {
                  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->mysql_table." VALUES('".$scores."',".$value.")";
               }
               $rs =  mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            }
         }   
      }
   }

   /* Create the scores table */
   function createTable() {
      $conn = mysql_connect($this->mysql_host,$this->mysql_user,$this->mysql_pass); 
      $rs = mysql_select_db($this->mysql_db,$conn);
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$this->mysql_table." ( `scrore_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `scrore_title` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '', `scrores` char(12) NOT NULL default '', `decimal_place` char(1) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '2', `value` float(15,8) NOT NULL,`date_updated` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', PRIMARY KEY(currency) ) ENGINE=MyISAM";   
      $rs =  mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
      $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->mysql_table." VALUES(1,'','GameA0','2',1,now())";
      $rs =  mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
      $this->downloadValueScores();   
   }
}
?>
```

then with that script mysql table/query created look like:

```
INSERT INTO `scrore_table` (`scrore_id`, `scrore_title`, `scrores`, `decimal_place`, `value`, `date_updated`) VALUES
(1, 'Game Class A0', 'GameA0', '2', 1.00000000, '2010-10-24 00:27:01');
```

but the database not auto populate, this seems function downloadValueScores() not work correctly

I've tried fixing it and I think that's the direction I have to go but I just have no idea. also i am sorry, i am new to php.

Any help or pointers would be great and many thanks

Comment: The code seems to be PHP4. Can you use PHP5 in your solution?

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your php version info. actually i don't know if that code is PHP4, because i don't know the different, could you please let me know what look like for PHP5 suitable to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where from  do you get the information, that the query looks like that:

```
INSERT INTO `scrore_table` (`scrore_id`, `scrore_title`, `scrores`, `decimal_place`, `value`, `date_updated`) 
    VALUES (1, 'Game Class A0', 'GameA0', '2', 1.00000000, '2010-10-24 00:27:01');
```

?

When I look at the function downLoadValueScores, the query will made of this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->mysql_table." VALUES('".$scores."',".$value.")";
```

...this for sure will not build the query above, this will just produce an error, because you have only 2 values assigned for a row to be inserted into a table with 6 fields.

Comment: Hi Dr. Molle, You're absolutely right, i got an error: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" then i try to fixed it.

Comment: by replace: $sql = "UPDATE ".$this->mysql_table." SET value=".$value." WHERE scores='".$scores."'";

Comment: with: $sql = "UPDATE ".$this->mysql_table." SET value=".$value.",date_updated='now()' WHERE scores='".$scores."'";

Comment: and Replace: $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->mysql_table." VALUES('".$scores."',".$value.")";

Comment: with: $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->mysql_table." VALUES(1,'','".$scores."','2',".$value.",now())";

Comment: then the error disappear also my table already auto populate. but all scrore_id set to 1 (not auto increasing), and scrore_title also empty. do you have solutions please? BTW many thanks for your attentions.

Comment: To let the score_id increment, replace the 1 with NULL . How to set the score_title I cant tell you while the xml you've posted above not contains any information about the score_title.

Comment: when i replace 1 with 'NULL' now score_id set to 0 except the first field. there another way to insert score_title by add conditional to php code? let say using conditional array, if scrores = 'GameA0' then scrore_title = 'Game Class A0', etc... this is just my opinion, but i can't figure it with myself.

Comment: It's not easy to read the codes in the comments, could you please edit your question or add a new answer  with the things you currently have changed :)

Comment: OK Dr.Molle, I would be, You Awesome

Answer (score 0):

Molle, You're Right, Great.

now the scrore_id already auto increment,

history modified are:
at function createTable()
change

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$this->mysql_table." ( `scrore_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `scrore_title` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '', `scrores` char(12) NOT NULL default '', `decimal_place` char(1) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '2', `value` float(15,8) NOT NULL,`date_updated` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', PRIMARY KEY(scrore_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM";
```

to

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$this->mysql_table." ( `scrore_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `scrore_title` varchar(32) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '', `scrores` char(12) NOT NULL default '', `decimal_place` char(1) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '2', `value` float(15,8) NOT NULL,`date_updated` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', PRIMARY KEY(scrore_id) ) ENGINE=MyISAM";
```

**auto_increment** should be add after **scrore_id` int(11) NOT NULL**

then for function downloadValueScores()

change:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->mysql_table." VALUES('NULL','','".$scores."','2',".$value.",now())";
```

to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->mysql_table." VALUES(NULL,'','".$scores."','2',".$value.",now())";
```

the result my table/query scrore_id auto increment and also auto populate.

Regarding to scrore_title it similar to country code 3 letters and the name of country,  e.g.

```
if USA = 'United State'
if GBR = 'Great Britain'
if FRC = 'France' etc..
```

following to my issue

```
if scrores = 'GameA0' then scrore_title = 'Game Class A0'
if scrores = 'GameA1' then scrore_title = 'Game Class A1'
if scrores = 'GameA2' then scrore_title = 'Game Class A2'
```

in anothers word if found scrores = 'GameA0' then insert the scrore_title = 'Game Class A0'
etc..

scrores already figured from games_scores.xml but scrore_title i should figured with myself. is there idea how to solve this?

Many thanks for your helps so far.